# How do I use CSS to edit the table layout so I can padding does not increase table width?

Tags: css, html-table, padding

I'm programming pages exclusively for IE (corporate environment). Trying to achieve matching layout from separate tables stacked one on top of the other on the table.

Trying to use CSS table-layout:fixed, but encountering problems. Unless I set the padding in each cell to 0px, the resulting width of the table increases by 2px for every cell in the row.

I need there to be distance between the edge of the cell and the text, but I don't want that to affect the width of the table. How do I get padding and an exact fixed-width table?

Here's my code. Note that the DIV displays exactly 500px wide, but the table is wider.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height:30px;width:500px;background-color:Blue;">500px</div>
<table style="width:500px;table-layout:fixed;border-spacing:0px;"><tr>
    <td style="width:100px;background-color:#d0d0d0;">Text</td>
    <td style="width:100px;background-color:#d0d0d0;">Text</td>
    <td style="width:100px;background-color:#d0d0d0;">Text</td>
    <td style="width:100px;background-color:#d0d0d0;">Text</td>
    <td style="width:100px;background-color:#d0d0d0;">Text</td>
</tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making the border, and padding on the table equal 0 anywhere they are.

```
table, th, td {
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are less useful.  Further, you're missing a semi-colon.  Explain why this answer fixes the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Adding padding or margin to your `tds` via styling will increase their width, as you've experienced. But you can add margin to anything *inside* a table cell.

Example:

```
<td><span>Text</span></td>

td > * {
  margin: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Katie. I'm not sure that this will help because a) I would have to go through a considerable amount of code adding spans to everything, and b) the margin seems to affect only sides of the cell, giving no vertical space.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the CSS model achieves padding by adding to the width of the object, not by creating an internal margin within the object. The only way I could overcome this was by changing the width of each column in the example to 96px, thus accommodating for the inherent 2px of padding on either side of the text.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset the padding for your `td` elements. You do not need `table-layout: fixed;` on your tables and should consider to avoid inline style attributes on your elements.

The padding is due to the browsers' default stylesheets. If you want to remove all default styles you can take a look at “css resets”.

See the following code and a [live example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6K73/).

HTML

```
<div class="reference">500px</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.reference {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: blue;
}

table {
    width: 500px;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #d0d0d0;
    padding: 0; /* important */
}
```